# KineticJS JavaScript Save As FileSystem Option

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, filesystems, kineticjs

I am using KineticJS to create a web application which is a standalone application using html5, css and javascript.

I have the following piece of code to convert the present canvas into an imageURI.

```
function save()
{
    stage.toDataURL({
        callback: function(imageURL) {
            window.open(imageURL);
        },
        mimeType: 'image/png',
        quality: 1,
        height: 480,
        width: 640

    });
 }
```

The save() is triggered using a button's onclick property.

I have two issues to be solved :-

I want to be able to open a "Save As" dialog box when I click on this save button.

Rename the file, instead of "download.png" to present date time as the file name. For e.g., "020420130306PM.png" ( Date 02/04/2013 Time 0306 )

My stage size is 958 X 598 and I want to save the file as a 640 X 480. The height and width attributes in toDataURL function only crop off top 640 X 480 pixels of the canvas.  How do I compress the entire stage ( 958 X 598 ) into a ( 640 X 480 ) and save it.

My present solution is the one stated in KineticJS tutorial which is click on the save button, new page opens up with canvas image, right click the image, save as image, rename file from download.png to 020420130306PM.png and click save.

I solved the third part using setScale method and it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the second part which is renaming the file, however, I am restricted to chrome browser, and without the ability to save it anywhere else other than the default downloads folder.

There exists a `download` attribute in `<a>` tags. If `download = "myfilename.png"`then the file will be downloaded as `myfilename.png`

First of all, to force the browser to download the file, you should modify the imageURI.

`var newImageURL = imageURL.replace("data:image/png;base64","data:image/octet-stream;base64");`

Now, to add and modify attributes just use jQuery `attr()` function along with `click()`. For e.g.,

```
$('#saveAnchor').attr('download',filename);
$('#saveAnchor').attr('href',newImageURL);
```

And now trigger a fake click on the anchor link using `$('#saveAnchor')[0].click();`

So basically when the `save()` is called, all the above occur in the callback function.

But I would still like know if there is any possible method of being able to save the image using "Save As" dialog box without the use of PHP or AJAX.